# mysql query behaves differently when value is quoted

Tags: mysql, variables, types

MySQL 5.0, Acct is a varchar field, so why is the query behaving differently?

```
        select * 
        from acct_codes
        where Acct = 10100;
        /* returns a record */ 

        select * 
        from acct_codes
        where Acct = '10100';
        /* returns no record */
```

How can I troubleshoot this? Can I typecast this somehow to guarantee I will always get the record? Please help.

Comment: Can you show what is returned by the first query?

Comment: The problem was carriage returns in the data, which must have happened when the data were populated into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I did a dump of the table and there was a carriage return at the end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can cast to INTEGER:

```
CONVERT( '10100', SIGNED INTEGER );
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is it is a varchar(6) ... not sure how integer is even coming into the picture here ... hmmmmm